# Using the digits 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, find the number of 8-digit sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Using the digits 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, find the number of 8-digit sequences (it may begin with 0) that can be written so that the difference between any two consecutive digits is 1.

Examples of such 8-digit sequences are 01234343, 12321010, 23232323.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know the multiplication principle?  How about counting the two digit sequences by hand?  That might help your intuition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a somewhat general way to deal with this type of problem. Let $G$ be a simple graph with vertices $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and edges $\{(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)\}$. The adjacency matrix of $G$ is
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
0&1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&0&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Now how many directed paths of length 1 in this graph? Well there are 8, and as every such path would be recorded in the matrix $A$, it is also the sum of all numbers in $A$.

Here comes the interesting part: the number in the $(i,j)$-slot of $A^n$ is exactly the number of different directed paths of length $n$ from vertex $i-1$ to vertex $j-1$(try to convince yourself of it). As such, the number of  8-digit sequences that satisfy your condition is exactly the sum of all numbers in $$A^7=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 &14&0&13& 0\\
14 &0&27& 0&13\\
 0 &27&0&27& 0\\
13&  0 &27&0& 14\\
 0& 13&  0& 14&  0
\end{array}\right)$$
which is 216. There are also some tricks to help you calculate the matrix power, so you can actually obtain a general formula for this or maybe some generalized question.